# how to install xerces on linux as static library

Tags: linux, linker, g++, linker-errors, xerces

I am using xerces for parsing the xml files.I want to make it static and use it directly in my project.so I downloaded the source and built it.which gave me all .o files and built all those .o files with my project .o files using a makefile and g++ as linker but when i did compilation i am getting liking errors like the following

/home/harsha/Desktop/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.cpp:523: undefined reference to `_cxa_allocate_exception'

/home/harsha/Desktop/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.cpp:523: undefined reference to `_cxa_throw'

/home/harsha/Desktop/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.cpp:523: undefined reference to `_cxa_free_exception'

How can i clear these errors ?

and is -lnsl is required ?

how to install it ?

Comment: How are you using the g++, do you have include path setup correctly?

Comment: yes i compiled it with g++ and include path is correct but i fear i am missing some dependent library